# How to add sorting position to MySQL records?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 8 InnoDB Table that stores prices from price comparison sites for specific products of a particular day. Usually prices are sorted ASC so I thought it is not neccessary to save the SERP (position) to the record.

The functionality to save the position has been added now and I am looking for a way to add this information for the old records. It can be identified by sorting after price.

Shema:

```
create table shops_prices
(
    DATE        date               not null,
    SKU         char(10)           not null,
    MERCHANT_ID tinyint unsigned   not null,
    SHOP_ID     mediumint unsigned not null,
    PRICE       decimal(10, 2)     null,
    SERP        tinyint unsigned   null,
    primary key (DATE, SKU, MERCHANT_ID, SHOP_ID)
)
    comment 'Prices from shops within price comparison merchants like e.g. Idealo
';
```

Get results for one product for one day:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE date = currdate() and SKU = 123
ORDER BY price
```

Desired result example:

```
   date        SKU  price SERP
   2021-09-02  123  12.99 1
   2021-09-02  123  13.99 2
   2021-09-02  123  14.99 3
   2021-09-03  123  12.99 1
   2021-09-03  123  13.99 2
   2021-09-03  124  18.99 1
```

How could I update the existing records to add the position to all datasets? (1,2,3,..)

Comment: do u update SERP column at the end of the day or after insert or on a certain time or only a query. If the price is at same day at same sku then what will be the order i.e it is incremental or same position.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to alter the existing records. New records are already saved with the info. Lowest price for sku on a day  is 1 the second lowest 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER() is used for given a serial based on sku and date where smaller price comes first. If WHERE condition needed for particular searching then enable it otherwise disable WHERE clause. use shop_id and merchant_id at partition column along with other two if needed. Use CTE for ranking the position then Update with main table.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
WITH t_cte AS (
      SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku, date ORDER BY price) row_num
      FROM shops_prices
      WHERE sku = 123 AND date <= '2021-09-05'
)
UPDATE shops_prices s
INNER JOIN t_cte t
        ON s.Date = t.Date
        AND s.SKU = t.SKU
        AND s.MERCHANT_ID = t.MERCHANT_ID
        AND s.SHOP_ID = t.SHOP_ID
        AND s.price = t.price
SET s.SERP = t.row_num
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51c3eecd19a5b6367722c6905235a5ed

Comment: @merlin if my answer really help you then please mark it as accepted along with upvote so that any one can pick this answer without any doubt when needed.

Comment: WOW! Thank you, it worked. I am amazed how much one can learn on SO, even when you believe you are quite good at something, this is a whole new level for me. Never used WITH, OVER, PARTITION and ROW_NUMBER before. Can you point me to a place/book where I can learn more about similar things?

Comment: Welcome @merlin. You can browse the url  https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Prior to mysql 8, you would use variables for this:

```
set @last_date=date(0);
set @last_sku='';  # may need to set collation for this string
set @last_serp=0;
update shops_prices
    set serp=@last_serp:=if(
        @last_date=date && @last_sku=sku,
        @last_serp+1,
        if((@last_date:=date) && (@last_sku:=sku),1,1)
    )
order by date,sku;
```